# Calculate areas in ha (hectares) with gdal?

Tags: python, gdal, area, numpy, reclassify

I would like to calculate using gdal certain areas in ha (hectares) for a reclassified raster. Can somebody help me with this?
Here is the reclassification:

```
#RBR reclassification to USGS burn severity values

arr = np.array(RBR)

level1 = (arr >= -0.500) & (arr <= -0.251) #Enhanced Regrowth, high (post fire)
level2 = (arr >= -0.250) & (arr <= -0.101) #Enhanced Regrowth, low (post-fire)
level3 = (arr >= -0.100) & (arr <= 0.99) #Unburned
level4 = (arr >= 0.100) & (arr <= 0.269) #Low Severity
level5 = (arr >= 0.270) & (arr <= 0.439) #Moderate-low Severity
level6 = (arr >= 0.440) & (arr <= 0.659) #Moderate-high Severity
level7 = (arr >= 0.660) & (arr <= 1.300) #High Severity

levels = [level2, level3, level4, level5, level6, level7]
reclass_values = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

reclassed_arr = np.where(level1,-2, arr)
for level, val in zip(levels, reclass_values):
    reclassed_arr = np.where(level, val, reclassed_arr)
```

And this is the burn area:

```
#Calculate burn area

reclass = reclassed_arr
k = ['Unburned hectares', 'Low severity hectares', 'Moderate-low severity hectares', 'Moderate-high severity hectares', 'High severity']
for level, val in zip(levels, reclassed_values):
    x = reclassed_arr[reclassed_arr == level]
    l = x.size*0.4
```

I got this error:

```
----> 8 print("%s: %.2f" % (k[reclassed_arr],1))
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

---

I would like to do something like this code to obtain the size of the different category areas.

```
reclass = reclassify(clipped_ds_rasterband.ReadAsArray())
k = ['Unburned hectares', 'Low severity hectares', 'Moderate-low severity hectares', 'Moderate-high severity hectares', 'High severity']
for i in range(1,6):
  x = reclass[reclass == i]
  l= x.size*0.04
  print("%s: %.2f" % (k[i-1], l))
```

[image]

At this point I get the number of pixels for each category.
[image]

Comment: Where is the line, `print("%s: %.2f" % (k[reclassed_arr],1))`, in your code?  Have you looked at these answers to similar errors:  https://www.google.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+only+integer+scalar+arrays+can+be+converted+to+a+scalar+index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are trying to index a Python list with a `numpy` array and that is not possible.

It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish in your code but judging from the first paragraph of your question it seems like you are trying to calculate the area of some categories in your raster.

Imagine you have a dictionary with the categories and their values:

```
categories = {
    'Enhanced Regrowth, high (post fire)': -2,
    'Enhanced Regrowth, low (post-fire)': -1,
    'Unburned': 0,
    'Low Severity': 1,
    'Moderate-low Severity': 2,
    'Moderate-high Severity': 3,
    'High Severity': 4
}
```

Then, you can get the number of pixels for each category with the following code:

```py
for cat, val in categories.items():
    n_pixels = (reclassed_arr == val).sum()
```

To get the actual area, you have to multiply the number of pixels (`n_pixels`) by the pixel area. You can get the pixel area by multiplying the pixel x and y resolutions.

Using `gdal` it could be done with:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.Open(r'path\to\my\raster.tif', 0)
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
pixel_area = gt[1] * abs(gt[5])
```

Note that the pixel area unit depends on the spatial reference of your raster and you might have to do some conversions in order to achieve the area in hectares.

Comment: and for computational reasons the Y pixel size is negative (hence the `abs` function)